# How to trigger message without messaging bot first

Tags: facebook, chatbot, messenger, facebook-chatbot

I am learning the facebook api and I am curious how to do this.

On this website(https://botacademy.com/), they use manychat and you can click the opt in button (on web) and it automatically accesses your messenger inbox without prompts or auth.

It then sends you a programatic message. All of the tutorials I follow require the user to send a message first..

Do you know what endpoint of the API they are using to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I do not know what their code looks like, but:

**that is a [send to messenger](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/plugin-reference/send-to-messenger) button, which allows you to authenticate with a bot and an app, and sends your information to the webhook**.

This counts as interacting with the bot, because you clicked the button and opted into the experience.

[FBM Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2016/08/15/updated-messenger-platform-policies/) have this to say about opting into messages and send to messenger:

> How messaging is triggered:
>
> ...
>
> Person requests a message from a business via a plugin, such as Send to Messenger